# Changing Registered WireMockExtension Port

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, wiremock

Is it possible to change WireMockExtension port that has been registered during run time?

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class BaseIntegrationTest {
  ...
  @RegisterExtension
  protected WireMockExtension wm = WireMockExtension.newInstance().options(
      wireMockConfig().port(12345).extensions(NoKeepAliveTransformer.class)).build();
  
  public void changePort() {
    // wm change port to 123
  }

}
```

Any equal solution without using `@RegisterExtension` but still having the `wm` variable for stubbing is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WireMockExtension` just JUnit extension that manages a `WireMock` server instance's lifecycle. If you want to change port in runtime you would need to stop and start server.

Looking at [WireMockExtension implementation](https://github.com/JensPiegsa/wiremock-extension/blob/db4acd90e7ef29e9308780cf79bf2a8e4918047e/src/main/java/com/github/jenspiegsa/wiremockextension/WireMockExtension.java#L36), not sure it was designed for this use case. I would rather recommend to manage `WireMock` lifecycle without extension.

```
private WireMockServer wireMockServer;
private int wireMockPort = 1000;

@BeforeEach
void startWireMock() {
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(wireMockPort));
    wireMockServer.start();
    WireMock.configureFor(wireMockServer.port());
}

@AfterEach
void stopWireMock() {
    wireMockServer.stop();
}

void changePort(int port) {
    wireMockPort = port;
}
```

It would allow you to change port before each test. If you need more granular control and change it during the test you can do nothing like

```
void changePort(int port) {
    stopWireMock();

    wireMockPort = port;

    startWireMock();
}
```